# Microservice architecture communication between services causing multi day releases

Tags: architecture, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a .NET Core web REST API microservice architecture with 16 different microservices. We also have a common code library that each microservice uses. In that common code library there are the "Public Models" for each microservice. This library is automatically updated in the build pipeline whenever the public models project changes. We do this so that microservice A knows what the models of microservice B looks like, so that when microservice A calls microservice B (via RestSharp https calls) it has the correct Model schema to fill with the response. The down side to this is that whenever we update one of the "Public Models" for a microservice we have to redeploy all of the other services so they can have the updated model as well.

It's starting to become a big headache to make any change. This strategy seems like it's not going to scale well and become even worse as we add more services. It is currently a multi day process to release updates. This strategy also seems to void one of the biggest advantages of microservices, "Independently Deployable". The lead on this project as well as the PM are pushing back on making any change to how this works. I started reading "Building Microservices by Sam Newman" and reading some articles and watching youtube videos to build my case for a change.

Can anyone suggest some alternative ways of microservices communicating together that makes them not so tightly coupled? Or is the design of this how microservices works and I need to get on board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a classic distributed monolith. Below are a few ways you could go about fixing it. Personally I would start with API versioning and adjusting your build system and then implement a messaging broker.

## Decoupling methods:

### Messaging Brokers Instead of TCP

One thing that you could do is instead of using a tightly coupled TCP based communication system you might be able to use something like Apache Kafka, Fluvio, RabbitMQ, or another queue messaging solution. This would allow Pub/Sub messaging so you can loosely couple your microservices. For example let's imagine a system of two microservices an Email microservice and an Auth microservice. When a user signs up we need to send them a welcome email so with your current implementation we would make a TCP API call with all of the required information but in a message based system we could send something like this over an Apache Kafka Topic (Or preferred abstraction for your messaging system):

```json
{
  "email": "xyz@example.com",
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

This will allow a level of temporal decoupling because TCP implies a temporal dependency

### Circuit Breakers

If you don't want to implement a messaging service or this is impractical for certain calls another somewhat patchwork decoupling solution would be to implement [circuit breakers](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) in your microservices so singular failures do not cause cascade failures.

### Dependency Determination

Another one of the things you could do is modify your build step to only redeploy microservices that are dependent on the specific model that got changed so you can deploy them (somewhat) independently.

### API Versioning

Another thing you could do is add API versioning so you don't have to update all of your microservices at the same time but instead you do gradual deployments. In my opinion this is the biggest thing that will fix your issue.

### Additional

You should probably also take a look at this: https://www.capitalone.com/tech/software-engineering/how-to-avoid-loose-coupled-microservices/ it has a lot of helpful information about avoiding microservice coupling. And this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/426944/how-to-share-api-between-microservices which is another question about microservice API schema decoupling

Comment: Thanks Max. What you're saying makes sense and I'll check out the links you provided. I appreciate it.